# How do I use Azure Cognitive Translator to translate a textblock in UWP?

Tags: c#, xml, azure, uwp

I created an Azure profile, and signed up for a Azure Cognitive Translator service. Now I want to use the translator api to translate a bunch of textblock in UWP xaml. But I'm not sure how to link my xaml textblock into the translator class I created.

Here is the class I made:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace AlarmClockProject
{
    class translator
{
    private const string Key = "MY_API_KEY";

    private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient
    {
        DefaultRequestHeaders = { { "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", Key } }
    };
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var text = Console.ReadLine(); // read the textblock
            var translatedText = await Translate(text, "en");
            Console.WriteLine(translatedText); //put this into the textblock
        }
    }
    public static async Task<string> Translate(string text, string language)
    {
        var encodedText = WebUtility.UrlEncode(text);
        var uri = "https://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Http.svc/Translate?" + $"to={language}&text={encodedText}";
        var result = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
        return XElement.Parse(result).Value;
    }
}
}
```

And here is the xaml I wish to translate which is under a page_loaded event.

```
        List<Article> articles = await NewsApi.GetArticlesMain();
        newsHeadlineTB.Text = articles.First().title;
        descriptionTB.Text = articles.First().description;
        newsHeadline1TB.Text = articles.Last().title;
        description1TB.Text = articles.Last().description;
```

I want to translate newsHeadlineTB.text and descriptionTB.text. I'm not sure if it would clash with another class (newsapi.org). How do I link the translator.cs class into my mainpage xaml and translate this two textblocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call the translate method:

```
var language = "en";
List<Article> articles = await NewsApi.GetArticlesMain();
newsHeadlineTB.Text = await translator.Translate(articles.First().title, language);
descriptionTB.Text = await translator.Translate(articles.First().description, language);
newsHeadline1TB.Text = await translator.Translate(articles.Last().title, language);
description1TB.Text = await translator.Translate(articles.Last().description, language);
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Such a simple solution too!